# Output for ng-app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Why the output for second div tag is displaying normal? Why there is no binding of angular js with it?

Could you please explain me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular JS Demo</title>
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="scripts/Script.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp1" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        {{ first_name +" "+ last_name }}
    </div>

    <div ng-app>
        10 +20 = {{ 10 + 20 }}
        {{ 1 == 2 }}
        {{ ['ajay','kumar','hari','bag'][0] }}
    </div>
    <script>
        var my_module = angular.module("myApp1", []);
        var my_Controller = function ($scope) {
            $scope.first_name = "vijay";
            $scope.last_name = "kumar";
        }
        my_module.controller("myCtrl", my_Controller);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

-----------output------

vijay kumar

```
10 +20 = {{ 10 + 20 }} {{ 1 == 2 }} {{ ['ajay','kumar','hari','bag'][0] }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp1', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.first_name = "vijay";
  $scope.last_name = "kumar";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


  <body >
   <div ng-app="myApp1" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        {{ first_name +" "+ last_name }}
        <div>
        10 +20 = {{ 10 + 20 }}
        {{ 1 == 2 }}
        {{ ['ajay','kumar','hari','bag'][0] }}
    </div>
    </div>

    
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the AngularJS docs only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. The first ng-app found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. If you want to use another ng-app you should manually bootstap the app.

See the angularJS docs section for the detailed explanation.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

Answer (score 0):

From AngularJS [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) -

> only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML
>   document.

In other words, ng-app directive can be used only once in your entire application. S

In your case, ng-app is **limited** to just one div tag. Outside this div tag, angularjs' features won't be accessible.  you can have a parent div with the ng-app directive, followed by the current divs. Or simply but the directive in your body tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular JS Demo</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/Script.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp1"> <!-- parent div -->
        <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
            {{ first_name +" "+ last_name }}
        </div>

        <div ng-app>
            10 +20 = {{ 10 + 20 }}
            {{ 1 == 2 }}
            {{ ['ajay','kumar','hari','bag'][0] }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var my_module = angular.module("myApp1", []);
        var my_Controller = function ($scope) {
            $scope.first_name = "vijay";
            $scope.last_name = "kumar";
        }
        my_module.controller("myCtrl", my_Controller);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```